# Rails expects me to restart on every change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.1

My views are working as expected; every time I change something, it is immediately reflected on the page. But every time I make a change in a **controller**, **model**, or **config**, I have to restart the server in order for it to show.

I start my server with `rails s -e development` and it states this:

```
  => Booting Puma
  => Rails 4.1.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
  => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
  => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
  => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

My `config/environments/development.rb` looks like this:

```
  # -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
  Gvm::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => 'gmail.com',
  :user_name => '...',
  :password => '...',
  :authentication => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
  # Para debug apenas, é melhor que a linha abaixo seja adicionado apenas no ambiente de desenvolvimento
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true


  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  end
```

Any ideas of why I still have to restart it after each change?

---

**Conclusion (without a solution):**

At the end, it **[seems](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16678)** that this is a rails and mounted partitions bug. My Vagrant VirtualBox VM mounts a shared folder and, on doing that, rails can't properly deal with time synchronization between guest and host.

While I don't have a proper confirmation of this issue, it is what could explain the initial question.

Comment: Have you tried `config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false` ?

Comment: Yes, it was in the config file before. But as it didn't change anything, I removed it.

Comment: This is weird, can't think about anything causing the problem, Rails 4 is threadsafe in default , can you put that line again and reload your server ?

Comment: Do you use spring or zeus?

Comment: @Kiloreux you mean `config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false`? I added it again and still didn't work :(  @AlexeyShein No I don't use spring or zeus.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new Rails app then check if it auto refresh by default?

Comment: No, I haven't. But isn't that strange that my current app asks me to reload every time?

Comment: you wrote this file is `config/development.rb`, right? do you have `config/environments/development.rb` as well?

Comment: Are you using NFS through a VM or similar? There's a known issue with this setup in Rails 4.

Comment: possible issue with using puma in development mode? does it auto reload if you use webrick instead? try `rails server webrick`

Comment: @basia, I only have `config/environments/development.rb` (edited the question) @Drenmi, I mount a Virtualbox shared folder within my virtualized server, yes. It's supposed to work, but does this setup have any known issues? @house9 Thanks, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 8):

Please add this line in your `development.rb` file. It work for me.

```
config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false
```

**NOTE:**
With `VirtualBox` setup we have a very well know problem: [rails issue track](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16678)

**Solution**: You need to synchronize time between host and client due some changes in Rails 4.

Comment: Hmm... strange, I think the problem is with your web server `puma`. Normally rails use `WEBrick`.

Comment: please can you confirm me, are you using NFS through a VM  ?

Comment: I use Debian on a Virtualbox VM and all rails files are on a mounted partition.

Comment: Here is the problem with the virtualbox: [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16678)
With *VirtualBox* you need to synchronize time between host and client due some changes in Rails 4.

Comment: Great! Will try to sync time between guest and host. Will post my findings here afterwards.

Comment: Yes, please update me, if it work for you (also `accept my answer`). I will be very glad to know that.

Comment: I ended up giving up trying to fix this... I just created a vagrant brand new server and created my rails project there. Still the same issue. I just don't know what's going on and gave up trying... thanks for you effort though

Comment: hmm no worries. I think skiping `VM` and installing `ubuntu` on system will fix this issue. Pleasse try with this if you can.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me with Rails 5. I ended up using docker instead of vagrant for my rails projects. (it is also a lot faster)

Comment: This works in the start, but again after 5-10 times it worked, later same issue.

Answer (score 5):

Rails 4.1 comes with `spring` from the box, so it maybe your issue. Run `spring stop` and after that check if there are any spring processes left `ps ax | grep spring` and run `pkill -9 spring` if any. Restart Rails and look if reloading works as expected.

Comment: yeah, spring brings me nothing but trouble.

Comment: Not sure if I have spring (at least I didn't expect to have it). Probably not? `root@debian:/# spring stop
 -bash: spring: command not found`

Comment: Look into `bin` folder of your project, there should be a file `spring`. You can run it via `bin/spring`.

Comment: There is no spring inside the `bin` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check your **development.rb** file, there may be

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development, since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes, just make this **false**

```
  config.cache_classes = false
```